# Can i somehow access a value if i know its address?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory-address

say we have a variable

```
    int var = 3000;
    int *pt;
    pt=2293572; //where &var=2293572
```

**Question is basically indirectly accessing values stored at memory locations, by just knowing the memory address?**
If not in c,cpp can we use some other language for it?

Comment: Are you asking how to de-reference a pointer?

Comment: You can assign values to pointers. Try it.

Comment: It's also worth noting that on modern OSes different processes may have different virtual address spaces, so if you've been told somewhere that address 2293572 holds some interesting data, consider whether that's true for your process, as it might refer to another process's virtual address space or a physical memory location.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you are asking how to cast an integer to a pointer and assign a value to a memory location using it.

```
int var = 3000;
int *pt;
pt= (int*) 2293572; 

// Assignment
*pt = 2; // now var = 2
```

Note that when you do this, you should observe the usual caveats, as Matt McNabb mentioned below.

- whether the cast works is implementation-defined
- the address might not be correctly aligned for `int`
- you'd better make sure you have the right address

Comment: Usual caveats: whether the cast works is implementation-defined; and the address might not be correctly aligned for `int`; and of course you'd better make sure you have the right address :)

Comment: @MattMcNabb, Would you like me to incorporate your comment into the answer?

Comment: Up to you, it seems fine just having a comment

Answer (score 2):

The correct way for the example given in your question:

```
int var = 3000;
int *pt = &var;

int x = *pt; // read-access (same as 'int x = var')
*pt = 12345; // write-access (same as 'var = 12345')
```

---

If you have a "pure" address (without the name of the variable allocated at that address):

```
int *pt = (int*)2293572;

int x = *pt; // read-access
*pt = 12345; // write-access
```

If the underlying HW architecture **or** the designated compiler at hand do not support unaligned load/store operations, then you have to ensure that the address is divisible by the size of the data-type.

For example, in the above code you would have to assert that `2293572 % sizeof(int) == 0`.

Answer (score 2):

While running this program you might have got the address 2293572 for "var", but its not necessary that you will get the same address every time you run your program.
Therefore its not a good practice to, explicitly assign an address to a variable and then try to access the value at that address.
You need to use pointers if you want to play around with addresses in c

Try this :

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int var = 100; // initialise a variable
  int *ptr;      // declare a pointer variable; a pointer is used to store the address
                 // (logical address, to be specific ) of a variable.

  ptr = &var;    // assign the address of the variable to the pointer
  printf("\nvar = %d", *ptr); // access the value stored at that address. This is also  
                               // dereferencing.

}
```

Comment: Welcome to S.O., and +1 for your point about legitimacy of addresses - it's worthy of consideration, but also worth nothing that in OS/driver-level code it's not unusual to aim pointers at specific hardcoded memory addresses that the architecture's known to give specific significance - for example, the interrupt table on x86s under DOS., or addresses that are known to perform I/O on serial or parallel ports....

Answer (score 0):

Int car = 3000; //variable car
Int final; 
Int* ptr; // unassigned pointer

Ptr= &car; // variable ptr holds memory location of car.

final = *ptr // this is the dereference

Final will return the integer value 3000.

To be quick and simple, pointers point to memory locations. When you "dereference" you say..."Hey I don't want to know where the number is, I want to know what value is stored there.

The tricky part of c is that it uses dynamic memory allocation, so it will not maintain the same location every time.